# Rstudio save and open blank Rmarkdown file

Tags: r, encoding, rstudio, r-markdown

My Rmarkdown file appears to completely blank. I wrote my homework in a Rmarkdown file in Rstudio. But when I open it this morning, file Knit gave me blank windows.

Then, to check the setup way of previous Rmd, I open one Rmd file but Rstudio shown a blank file again.

So I follow the advice on the internet to "Reopen with Encoding", UTF-8 turned out helpful to show my previous Rmd.

[image: screenshot]

But, when I click "Reopen with Encoding" on my hw4, all content disappeared, and none of encoding looks right for my hw4.

And I believe I did something with encoding last night when saving the file, because the final project blocked down R session for a couple of times and some windows jumped out to save the files with certain encoding. I also noticed that in direction the rmd file are 0KB, and Jupyter Notebook also open a blank file for me.

How can I recover the content of hw4 content? Are there any chance to recover it or I can just rewrite the whole file?

Comment: I looks like you _do_ have content in that file, assuming you are referring to the main window in the background containing the syntax-coloured code. I would take a backup of the file first. Can you open it in Notepad or a text editor? Perhaps it can be pasted into a new UTF-8 file?